# laravel modify headers before authenticating (token based / api)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization, laravel-middleware

I have an api that used Dingo API. The current users therefore use a
`X-Api-Key` header for authentication. I now want to switch to laravels implemented API system which requires an `Authorization` header.

Is it possible to tell laravel which header to use.
Or preferrably:
Is there a hook that I can use to modify the headers (e.g. copy the X-Api-Key header value into the Authorization header), before authentication takes place?

Comment: You can do this using Laravel's middleware.

Answer (score 2):

You can create middleware like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ModifyHeader extends BaseAuthorize
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($authorization = $request->header('X-Api-Key')) {
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', $authorization);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then you need to add this middleware to $middlewareGroups or $routeMiddleware for example like this:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        // ... 
        \App\Http\Middleware\ModifyHeader::class,
    ],
    // ...
 ];
```

and then you should make sure that routes you want to make the change are in `api` middleware. Of course you can also create custom middleware group for this or apply this for selected routes.

Then for example if you add such route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('/test', function () {
        dd(request()->header('Authorization'));

    });
});
```

You should get the same value that is passed in `X-Api-Key` header.

Comment: is it in the web or the api middlewareGroups ??

Comment: @Maraboc You are right, it's better to demonstrate this in `api` middleware for such usage although it depends on author application how exactly his middleware groups are organized